# Dead alien found by a trucker, but the alien is revived by his suit

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

What sci-fi book is about a dead alien found by a trucker. The alien's suit eventually revives him and he fights an alien armada. I think it's called "Fred the Dead" but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Is it a full book, or just a short story? Please go through the list of questions at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and edit the answers to as many as you can into your question.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly not "Fred the Dead", but rather "[Jed the Dead](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?8997)" by Alan Dean Foster.

From the review at [Publisher's Weekly](https://www.publishersweekly.com/978-0-441-00399-0):

> Ross Ed Hagen is a king-sized Texan with one desire in life: to see
> the Pacific Ocean. But during a rest stop on [h]is drive west he
> discovers a pint-sized, three-limbed corpse in a space suit which
> rather changes his trip. Jed, as Ross names the body, never moves a
> muscle, and yet, he possesses a variety of unearthly powers, ranging
> from telepathically inducing cosmic visions, to blasting car jackers
> with laser beams, even providing patter for a ventriloquism act.